# How to sort options in dropdown using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have dropdown with array of objects for options:

```
<select class="auc-form-control" ng-options="dataValue.Id as dataValue.Name for (dataKey, dataValue) in Types" ng-model="name">
</select>
```

Options are sorted by Id like this:

```
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
...
```

**How can I sort options in a natural way?** [1, 2, 3, ...]

Comment: Could you please show what does the `Types` object look like?

Comment: You are lacking information here. As Artyom in his answer and comment already pointed out, [0, 1, 10, 11] **is** the natural order, i.e. for numbers. From your question it is unclear how you want the objects to be ordered or what you consider "natural". Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your `Id` properties are strings (not numbers).

In that case, you have to use a custom getter to get a value for sorting. For example:

```
$scope.getSortValue = function (item) {
  return +item.Id; // convert string to number
};
```

Then use it with the `orderBy` filter like this:

```
<select class="auc-form-control" ng-options="dataValue.Id as dataValue.Name for (dataKey, dataValue) in Types | orderBy:getSortValue" ng-model="name"></select>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/TfVrfhaiuBKbPpHSqp4Q?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

What about orderBy filter that can be used like this:

```
"ng-options="dataValue.Id as dataValue.Name for (dataKey, dataValue) in Types" | orderBy:'Id'"
```

Please see this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/393/)** with your example.